# Is a slowed creature denied the action to break free from Hold Person spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, actions

[Hold person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person/) is a spell which prevents the target from doing anything except attempting to escape the spell as a full round action on a failed save. [Slow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) is a spell which denies targets some actions on their turn while under effect of the spell.

As it is stated in hold person that breaking free is a full round action, if they are slowed does this make it impossible to escape from hold person?

Hold Person

> The subject becomes paralyzed and freezes in place. It is aware and breathes normally but cannot take any actions, even speech. Each round on its turn, the subject may attempt a new saving throw to end the effect. **This is a full-round action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity.** A winged creature who is paralyzed cannot flap its wings and falls. A swimmer can’t swim and may drown.

Slow

> An affected creature moves and attacks at a drastically slowed rate. Creatures affected by this spell are staggered and can take only a single move action or standard action each turn, but not both **(nor may it take full-round actions)**. Additionally, it takes a -1 penalty on attack rolls, AC, and Reflex saves. A slowed creature moves at half its normal speed (round down to the next 5-foot increment), which affects the creature’s jumping distance as normal for decreased speed.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80036/how-does-slow-affect-round-long-casting-times?rq=1

Comment: @ravery I had no idea that it was possible to split up an action this way. Opens up some new possibilities and allows you to keep moving I guess.

Comment: There are some limits on it though:  "You can't use this action to start or complete a full attack, charge, run, or withdraw."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although not a duplicate, this question is strongly related [How does Slow affect round-long casting times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80036/how-does-slow-affect-round-long-casting-times?rq=1)

The relevnt quote from the answer is:

> From "standard actions" section:
>
> > The "start full-round action" standard action lets you start undertaking a full-round action, which you can complete in the following round by using another standard action. You can't use this action to start or complete a full attack, charge, run, or withdraw.

Thus, you would use the Standard Action of one turn to begin the save and complete it with the Standard Action of the next turn. Therefore, the slowed creature would get a save every other round instead of every round.